# invalid key in Dictionary

Tags: c#, collections

Why do dictionaries not just return `null` when an invalid key is used to index into the collection?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because generic dictionaries could contain instances of a value type, and null is not valid for a value type.  For example:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
DateTime date = dict["foo"]; // What should happen here?  date cannot be null!
```

You should instead use the TryGetValue method of dictionary:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
DateTime date;

if (dict.TryGetValue("foo", out date)) {
    // Key was present; date is set to the value in the dictionary.
} else {
    // Key was not present; date is set to its default value.
}
```

Also, a dictionary that stores reference types will still store null values.  And your code might consider "value is null" to be different from "key does not exist."

Comment: This doesn't really address the reason for the design decision; they could just have easily made it return `default(DateTime)` instead of null.

Comment: @Extragorey Yes it does, in particular the final sentence: whatever the "not found" value is, you may need to store that value as meaningful. If fetching a key that isn't found returns `default(DateTime)` then you can't distinguish between "value is `default(DateTime)`" and "key isn't present," at least without an additional call to `ContainsKey()` (which would unnecessarily double the cost of the operation). For a dictionary containing a reference type as the value, maybe `null` is a meaningful state apart from "key isn't present."

Comment: Thanks, that explanation makes more sense.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft decided that =)
Do an inline check to avoid that.

```
object myvalue = dict.ContainsKey(mykey) ? dict[mykey] : null;
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using

[Dictionary.TryGetValue Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=VS.90).aspx)

or maybe

[Dictionary.ContainsKey Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=VS.90).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Practical reason:  Because a Dictionary could store a null value.  You wouldn't be able to differentiate this case with an exception, in your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Boom!

http://github.com/jsonmez/Defaultable-Dictionary

http://simpleprogrammer.com/2011/08/14/making-switch-refactorings-better-defaultable-dictionary/